# Erro 500 em Biblioteca Asp.Net Awesome

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Eu encontrei navegando pela internet essa biblioteca [`ASP.net Awesome`](http://aspnetawesome.com/). Achei ela bem funcional e fácil de se usar.

De acordo com a documentação pra se usar um *helper* chamado `Lookup`, precisa se ter um `controller` e chamar o *helper* no *cshtml*. O que acontece é que, no meu projeto, tá exatamente igual ao da documentação(*o código*), e to tendo um *erro 500* e não sei exatamente porque.

Já pesquisei e não consegui resolver o erro, será que alguém poderia me ajudar ?

- Explicando o Lookup faz: Ele abre um *popup* com uma lista do que tem em sua tabela pra você selecionar e popular um campo de texto. Tem como fazer um procura pra achar exatamente o que você quer. E é exatamente nesse método *Search* que ta dando erro, ele teria que carregar todos os meus registros do banco de dados, os nomes dos alunos. mas ele dá *erro 500*.

O código do controller é esse:

```cs
public class AlunoLookupController : Controller
{
    private EntidadesContext db = new EntidadesContext();
    //Aqui ele pega o item que foi selecionado e joga no campo de texto 
    public ActionResult GetItem(int? v)
    {
        var o = db.Alunos.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == v) ?? new Aluno();

        return Json(new KeyContent(o.Id, o.Nome));
    }
    // E aqui ele faz a busca dos registros no banco e exibe no popup
    //E aqui tabém dá erro, ele não acha nenhum registro e só fica carregando
    public ActionResult Search(string search, int page)
    {
        search = (search ?? "").ToLower().Trim();
        var list = db.Alunos.Where(f => f.Nome.ToLower().Contains(search));
       
        return Json(new AjaxListResult
        {
            Items = list.OrderBy(n => n.Nome).Skip((page - 1) * 7).Take(7).Select(o => new KeyContent(o.Id, o.Nome)),
            More = list.Count() > page * 7
        });
    }
}
```

Tenho certeza que problema ta no código que eu puxei de lá, mas não sei o que é que ta acontecendo.

O erro que aparece é o seguinte:

> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.NotSupportedException: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Alguém será que pode me ajudar ? Tentei usar ela aqui de acordo com a documentação, mas não deu certo de jeito nenhum... O VS não reconhece a dll e não reconhece nada !

Comment: Você pode [edit] sua pergunta explicando melhor o que está tentando fazer e o que está dando errado. Deixe a pergunta mais específica e dê detalhes para as pessoas poderem entender o problema e te ajudar.

Comment: Eu já arrumei, fiz um update do erro que estou tendo !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos lá, eu resolvi o problema. O problema é que eu acho que o código é meio antigo, e por isso não funcionou bem do jeito que está no site. Então eu pesquisei e usei como referência esse [link aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571084/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti). o que acontece é que ele não estava conseguindo conectar com o banco pra fazer a lista, então tive adaptar o código, que está logo abaixo para quem quiser usar a biblioteca também:

```
public class AlunoLookupController : Controller
{
    private EntidadesContext db = new EntidadesContext();
    public ActionResult GetItem(int? v)
    {
        var o = db.Alunos.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == v) ?? new Aluno();

        return Json(new KeyContent(o.Id, o.Nome));
    }

    public ActionResult Search(string search, int page)
    {
        search = (search ?? "").ToLower().Trim();
        var lista = db.Alunos.Where(f => f.Nome.Contains(search)).ToList();
        return Json(new AjaxListResult
        {
            Items = lista.OrderBy(f => f.Nome).Skip((page - 1) * 7).Take(7).Select(o => new KeyContent(o.Id, o.Nome)),
            More = lista.Count() > page * 7
        });
    }
}
```

Lembrando que esse código ai em cima, tem que estar no controller que você quer manipular a informação, mas fora das actions normais que são criadas, por exemplo Home, ele tem que estar abaixo dessa action, mas na mesma classe como abaixo:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

E aqui em baixo dele o código do controller que o [ASP.net Awesome](http://aspnetawesome.com/) usa:

```
public class AlunoLookupController : Controller
{
    private EntidadesContext db = new EntidadesContext();
    public ActionResult GetItem(int? v)
    {
        //Os códigos das actions
    }
}
```